# Typescript generics extending class and interface

Tags: typescript

I have a Typescript class which includes a generic which needs to extend another class and implement an interface. Here is an example

```
interface IHasImage {
  imageUrl():string; 
}
class Model {
}
class View<T extends Model & IHasImage> {
}
```

This is the sort of syntax I have seen elsewhere but is there a way of doing this in Typescript?

edit:
Try pasting the following in to the playground:http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground

```
...[removed edit 1 code]
```

**edit 2: Answer and reasoning**

(I apologise, the first example had a few flaws!)
I have marked the correct answer below, although it probably needs a few pointers as outlined in this github issue (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1885)

Given the following code you can see the methodology works.

[image: playground screenshot]

The only other thing to say is that trying to `implement` the interface from a class that does not extend the base class also fails. However because Typescript checking is **based on the structure of the object**, it will succeed if you manually add the `name` property to the class.

[image]

This is also why it succeeds with the `ModelCorrect` which `extends` but doesn't `implements`.

Comment: i think there is a bug in the example.  this in the constructor is not the generic type value. Class should have a   Model:T property or constructur can accept a   value:T argument

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like this is the only way of doing it that I can find. Not perfectly clean but it does the right thing.

```
interface IHasImage extends Model{  
  imageUrl():string; 
}

class Model {
}

class View<T extends IHasImage> {
}
```

Here is a screenshot from the playground verifying that it works:

[image: playground]

**Edit:** Added correct workaround.

Comment: I tried that, and it does compile but I don't think it does what I'm looking for becuase when I try to do `this.model.imageUrl()` it complains the T doesn't have an `imageUrl` function

Comment: i'll give that a go, I thought I tried that but might not have done

Comment: This almost works, It allows correct use of the `model` property however for some reason it doesn't restrict to classes that extend the base class... I have created an issue in github explaining this further https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1885

Comment: There are serious issues with the provided example. If T needs to extend Model and Implement IHasImage the real implementation class is missing. That would be something like 

`class ModelWithImage extends Model Implements IHasImage {}`

In that case, that class can be use as the Type parameter constraint, or an additional interface can be added.

Comment: This answer has the right idea which is why I have marked it but I have added a full explanation (and fixed the code! ...sorry) in an edit above

Answer (score 31):

Typescript is not so restrictive as Java or C# so you can do things like that:

```
interface IHasImage {
    imageUrl():string; 
}

class Model {
}

// use the Model class like an interface
interface IHasImageModel extends IHasImage, Model{
}

class View<T extends IHasImageModel> {
    constructor(arg :T){
       arg.imageUrl();
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
In TypeScript 1.6 you can use Intersection types:

```
interface IHasImage {
    imageUrl():string; 
}

class Model {
}

class View<T extends IHasImage & Model> {
    constructor(arg :T){
       arg.imageUrl();
    }
}
```

Comment: what does `class View<T>` actually mean?

Comment: @SuperUberDuper This is a question for a new stackoverflow entry. In short it is the typescript way for a generic class https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-classes You can use this class with all types which fulfilled the  requirements "extens IHasImage & Model"

Answer (score 4):

Missing in the example is what T will be:

In the example below i have added an implementation for T, that can be used as the generic constraint.

```
interface IHasImage {
  imageUrl():string; 
}

class Model {
}

class ModelWithImage extends Model implements IHasImage {

    imageUrl():string
    {
     return "http://thepetwiki.com/images/thumb/Kitten.jpg/400px-Kitten.jpg";
    }   
}


class View<T extends ModelWithImage>
{
    value:T;

    constructor(arg:T)
    {   
        this.value=arg;
    }       
}
```

Comment: the model extends is too specific here unfortunately as many kinds of model may have the same `IHasImage` functionality