# Typescript: HOC prop type for union type component prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have component with prop like:

```js
setSelectedValue: (value: number | string) => void;
```

And I'd like to make HOC, that has setSelectedValue prop to which only numbers can be passed and which be also passed as prop to original component, I see it's type like so:

```js
setSelectedValue: (value: number) => void;
```

When I try to make it I get TS error message:

```
Type '(value: number) => void' is not assignable to type '(value: number | string) => void'.
```

How can I get desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your component (**comp.tsx**):

```
import React from 'react';
import hocComp from './hocComp';

interface Props {
  setSelectedValue: (value: number | string) => void; // number | string
}

class Comp extends React.Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return <div>Comp</div>;
  }
}

export default hocComp<Props>(Comp); // LINE 1
```

and HOC (**hocComp.tsx**):

```
import React from 'react';

interface Props {
  setSelectedValue: (value: number) => void; // number // LINE 2
}

export default function hocComp<P extends object>(
  WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<P>
) {
  return class extends React.Component<Props> {  // LINE 3  
    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props as P} />; // LINE 4
    }
  };
}
```

were defined the way shown above, you can use it (in App.tsx) without any *TypeError*:

```
import React from 'react';
import Comp from './comp';

export default function App() {
  function setSelectedValue(value: number) {
    console.debug(value);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
      <Comp setSelectedValue={setSelectedValue} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-pine-dq78v?file=/src/App.tsx:0-385).

---

**Here is an explanation:**

1. **While calling the HOC**, *We passed **component** and its **Props** interface into the HOC.*

   `export default withComp<Props>(Comp); // LINE 1`
2. **Definition of HOC**: We received passed interface into a generic variable `P` and the passed component `WrappedComponent` declared its type to be a **React ComponentType with P as props interface**

   `export default function withComp<P extends object>(
     WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<P>
   ) {`
3. **Finally, inside render of HOC**: We invoke passed component, **WrappedComponent** and pass it **all the props** which has interface defined as in the HOC itself (LINE 2) - (note that these props are used in the class returned by the HOC - LINE 3)

   `return <WrappedComponent {...(this.props as P)} />; // LINE 4`
4. **Now as you can see**, `P has -> setSelectedValue: (value: number | string) => void` and `Props has -> setSelectedValue: (value: number) => void` which should throw as **TypeError**, which we avoided by **Type Casting** as LINE 4. You can try removing this Type Casting, it will start showing errors.

You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28273714/2873538) post to understand **generics** in TypeScript.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was looking for!
I was wondering, what to do, if I'd wanted to create Container for this component?
I'd be very grateful if you helped me to understand ways of doing it.

Comment: My first suggestion was to use generics, but I got stuck with it

Comment: Yes, would be great!

Comment: Thank you a ton!