# how to extend a class with generic in typescript?

Tags: typescript

for example there is a class like this:

```
const app = new class App {
  constructor() {
    this.items = {};
    return new Proxy(this, this as any);
  }
  get (target, prop) {
    if (prop === 'bind') return target.bind;
    return target.items[prop];
  }
  bind (name, data) {
    this.items[name] = data;
    return this;
  }
}
```

how to implement such a construction in a typescript with generics and what would be available later like this:

```
app.bind('version', '1.0.0');
app.bind('configs', {path: '/', env: 'local'});

app.version.length;
app.configs.path.length;

let is_local = app.configs.env === 'local';
```

I was already desperate in search of (((

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28274279/7737346)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really see how a `class` helps you with such a dynamic proxy, so I will write something without using a `class` that still gives what I think might be the desired behavior.

The problem with treating `app` as an expando object is that TypeScript's static type system doesn't really want to allow you to do that.  If `app` isn't known in advance to have a type named `version`, then TypeScript's compiler won't want to let you read such a property.  You can use a [string index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) to allow any property whatsoever, but this is probably too lax for your use case.  Ideally, I think, you'd like to call `app.bind(key, value)` and then *after that* the compiler knows that `app` has a property at index `key` whose value type is `typeof value`.

This is just about possible by making the `bind()` method of the `app` object an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions), which narrows the type of `app`.  There is a pretty big caveat with assertion functions; in order to use them you must explicitly annotate `app`'s type (see [microsoft/TypeScript#33580](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33580)).

Here's one way to do it:

```
interface _App<T> {
  bind<K extends PropertyKey, V>(key: K, val: V): asserts this is App<Id<T & Record<K, V>>>;
}
type Id<T> = T extends infer U ? { [K in keyof U]: U[K] } : never;
type App<T = {}> = Readonly<T> & _App<T>;
function makeApp(): App {
  const items: any = {};
  const bind = (name: any, data: any) => items[name] = data;
  return new Proxy({} as any, {
    get(target, prop) {
      if (prop === 'bind') return bind;
      return items[prop];
    }
  })
}
const app: App = makeApp(); 
//       ~~~~~ <----- this annotation is required
```

The type `App<T>` is treated as both a `Readonly<T>` (meaning you can read all the same properties as `T`) and as an `_App<T>`.  An `_App<T>` is an interface with a `bind<K, V>(key: K, val: V)` method that acts as an assertion function which adds a property with key `K` and value `V` to the `T`.

The `makeApp()` function returns an `App<{}>`, or an `App` with no extra expando properties yet.  It does this via [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).  Note that the `get()` handler has to be part of the second object passed into `new Proxy()`.  I've got `items` as a closure-hidden object that sits inside the body of the `makeApp()` function, and when you read and write expando properties you are dealing with this `items` object and not `this.items`.

---

Let's see if it works:

```
// const app: App<{}>
app.bind('version', '1.0.0');
// const app: App<{ version: string; }>
app.bind('configs', { path: '/', env: 'local' });
// const app: App<{ version: string; configs: { path: string; env: string; };}>

console.log(app.version.length); // 5
console.log(app.configs.path.length); // 1

let is_local = app.configs.env === 'local';
console.log(is_local); // true
```

It looks good.  After you call `app.bind('version', '1.0.0')`, the type of `app` changes from `App<{}>` to `App<{ version: string; }`.  So the compiler understands that, and then later the compiler allows you to read a `string` value from `app.version`.

---

I don't know if this meets all your use cases, but hopefully it's at least a path forward.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.0.5#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)

Comment: If I add a new method with the same conditions: 
`compute<K extends PropertyKey, V>(key: K, val: V): asserts this is App<Id<T & Record<K, V>>>;`
then the autocomplete does not work for me in ide.

Comment: This follow-up question needs a [mcve] ("does not work for me" is not really enough info) and probably its own post since it's out of scope for the original question.  Good luck!